# create a choice form in django that contains unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-forms

i have this choice form :

```
class rqtime(forms.ChoiceField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(rqtime, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.required = True
        self.initial = True    
        self.choices=(('1','my_unicode'),('2','soon'),('3','1day'),('4','1week'),('5','3week'))
        global mydic
        mydic=dict(self.choices)

    def clean(self, value):
        return mydic[value]
```

i used `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and `-*-coding:utf-8-*-` but after runserver this is the raised error from `'my_unicode'`:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd9'
```

how can i decode an unicode in form django !

Comment: What python version are you using? I can't replicate your error. Also why are you using global mydic?

Comment: i use python 2.7 ... ! the error raise because of ('1','my_unicode') ... and global is for clean function !

Comment: I've copied your class and added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning. Everything worked fine. Maybe try changing `'my_unicode'` to `u'my_unicode'`.

Comment: thank you ! i thought i done this ... ! because i examine several ways i forget somethings ! i use u'my_unicode' and it work well !

Comment: Great it worked. I'll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `u` prefix before your unicode string, change `'my_unicode'` into `u'my_unicode'`.

```
self.choices=(('1',u'my_unicode'),('2','soon'),('3','1day'),('4','1week'),('5','3week'))
```

You can read more about [Unicode Type in Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type).